# How can I display an image on a flask server?

Tags: python, image, flask

I am trying to write a simple program that shows a random meme every time you log onto the flask url, my question:
Is there an easy way to display the meme on the website?
(the memes are in a directory of mine)
Thank you!

Comment: To answer your question as you have asked it..... yes it is possible.

Comment: Please try to improve your question. It is lacking many details and shows no code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a number for every image e.g. 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc. On the server-side you can generate a random number. On the client you need to put a jinja code(in your HTML template):

```
<img src="{{number}}.jpg" />
```

Is that simple

Comment: I cannot get it to work, every time i try to log onto the server it shows an error message:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: I think this is an error from nginx